# Google Maps fitBounds not applying padding when only one point

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, fitbounds

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API.

Everytime the user search for some place, I show the marker of each place in my map and I use `fitBounds` to set the viewport to contain the given bounds.

As I have a panel above the map of `400px width` on the right side, I apply a `400px` of right padding in the `fitBounds`.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)); //this line is executed inside a loop for every place
map.fitBounds(bounds, {right: 400});
```

When I have multiple points inside the bounds, the `fitBounds` works great applying the padding. But when I have only one point inside the bounds, the `fitBounds` does not apply the padding. Instead of that it works like `panTo`, only changing the center of the map.

Is that a bug in Google Maps API? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be a bug on the API, you can report it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558438).

A workaround for the problem is using the [panBy](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.panBy) method when there is only one point after calling the `fitBounds` method, like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdoq9fae/1/).

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)); //this line is executed inside a loop for every place
map.fitBounds(bounds, {right: 400});
if (pointsCount == 1) { // initialize the var and use the loop to count
    map.panBy(200, 0); // has to be half of needed padding
}
```

Comment: Yeap it seems to be a bug. I reported it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139464498). That `panBy` workaround really works for me, thanks.